# How can I import a table from MongoDB into Databricks with case-insensitive field name handling?

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, databricks

I need to import a table from MongoDB that contains a mix of upper and lower case field names. For example:

Document 1:

_id: 100
account_id: 1001
abc: "asd"

Document 2:

_id: 201
ACCOUNT_ID: 1023
XYZ: "qwe"

When I execute the following code in Databricks, I encounter the following error:

> [COLUMN_ALREADY_EXISTS] The column 'account_id' already exists. Consider choosing another name or renaming the existing column.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
from cb_databricks.predefined import spark

mongo_df = (
    spark.read.format("mongo")
    .option("database", database)
    .option("collection", mongo_table)
    .option("spark.mongodb.input.uri", connect_string)
    .load()
)
mongo_df.write.mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").saveAsTable("databricks_table")
```

How can I modify this code or set appropriate options to handle case-insensitive field names when reading data from MongoDB into Databricks?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `spark.sql.caseSensitive` Spark configuration to `"true"`:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "true")
```

But then downstream consumers will need to use it too. It's better to have some code to normalize names.

Comment: After this change, I am getting. Found duplicate column(s) in the metadata update: amount, pk, account_id, etl_loaded_at_ts, currency